# Number of Suggested URLs in Firefox

Tags: firefox

All,
When I type the following in the address bar in firefox

- key_word

Firefox suggests me a few number of URLs that contain the key word.
I wanted to know if there is a way to increase the number of URLs suggested by firefox to say 20 or all?

Also I was actually trying to browse all the URLs i have book marked with a set of tags, say tag1, tag2 etc...

is there a way I can specify to see links/URLs with specific tags?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, type `about:config` in the location bar and search the entry `browser.urlbar.maxRichResults`. You'll be able to change the number.

For the second question, you can use customizable characters in the location bar. For example, the symbol `+` means to search tags. Therefore, if you type `key_word +`, you'll search bookmarks tagged `key_word`. [More information about customizable characters.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Location_Bar_search#Location_Bar_search_.28internal_-_Auto_Complete.29)