# How to see more resuls when searching open tabs in Firefox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

I am using % for searching in my open tabs in Firefox. But the problem is that I can't get more than 9 results, others just don't show up. How do I fix that? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVxGs.png)

Comment: Another similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/304534/number-of-suggested-urls-in-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `about:config`. Change the value for `browser.urlbar.maxRichResults`. By default it is 10, set it to a higher value of whatever you want.

Comment: Is it possible to change this dynamically? I mean to have the default value of 10 but show another 10 by pressing hotkeys or something.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The only way to control this is through the about:config setting. If you wanted to create an AutoHoykey script or something to change that setting you could do that.